Unable to launch Roscore
I am encountering issues while attempting to run TurtleBot2e. I followed the tutorial provided by  TurtleBot assuming it is still applicable for TurtleBot 2e. When I run ROSCORE from my workstation, I receive the following error:

I have verified the configuration in my bashrc file for TurtleBot. The following is the configuration of Turtlebot
# Environment variables to work with remote workstation
#export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.138
#export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.143:11311

# Customise turtlebot
# http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Customising%20the%20Turtle
#export TURTLEBOT_NAME=turtlebot
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL= burger

#export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=kinect
alias eb='nano ~/.bashrc'
alias sb='source ~/.bashrc'
alias gs='git status'
alias gp='git pull'
alias cw='cd ~/catkin_ws'
alias cs='cd ~/catkin_ws/src'
alias cm='cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make'
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://169.226.20.188:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=169.226.20.188

How can I solve the error?
